# Jackson serializes using @JsonProperty name in constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have been working on upgrading the Spring Boot version of one of my microservices, and I stumbled upon a strange behaviour. I have class like this:

```java
public class FilteredData {

    private final List<ShipmentData> shipments;

    public FilteredData(@JsonProperty("listShipments") List<ShipmentData> shipments) {
        this.shipments = shipments;
    }

    public List<ShipmentData> getShipments() {
        return shipments;
    }
}
```

The behaviour that I had before doing the upgrade was that, when deserialising, the name `listShipments` was used in the JSON object to map to the `shipments` property of the Java class. However, when serialising, it would write the `shipments` property with the name `shipments`, not `listShipments`.
The problem is that now it is using the name `listShipments` when both deserialising and serialising. I am not sure at what point this issue started happening, as my initial Spring Boot version was 1.5.7 and I am slowly upgrading all the way to 2.3.4. But I believe it started happening after version 2.0.0.

I don't know if this is being caused by some internal change in Spring Boot's Jackson autoconfiguration, or a change in the actual Jackson library, but I am having a hard time tracking what caused this and how to fix it.

EDIT: I noticed from the latest Spring Boot 1 version (1.5.22) to Spring Boot 2.0.0, the Jackson minor version was bumped (from 2.8 to 2.9). Could this have caused the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the issue! It was caused by a dependency being used by `spring-boot-starter-web` called `jackson-module-parameter-names`. This library provides a Jackson module named `ParameterNamesModule`, which, as per Spring Boot's Jackson Autoconfiguration, any Jackson module found in the classpath is automatically imported.

The description for this library in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8 says:

> Parameter names: support for detecting constructor and factory method ("creator") parameters without having to use @JsonProperty annotation. Provides com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule

I am not 100% sure still why this created the problem that it did, but removing it through Maven solved the issue:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this exact behaviour while switching from Spring Boot *1.5.7.RELEASE* to *2.0.0.RELEASE*. First, I added the parent and the *spring-boot-starter-web* dependency. Then, I created a simple `@RestController`, used the POJO you provided and replaced `ShipmentData` with `String`. When I manually create a Jackson `ObjectMapper`, I could not reproduce the issue across the two releases.

The most interesting part: When you rename the parameter name of the constructor to something other than `shipments`, it seems to work fine. This could possibly be a bug in Jackson or somewhere in the Spring Framework which manifests only when the getter matches the parameter name in the constructor.

I suggest to use `@JsonAlias` to define the alternative name that should be accepted during deserialization:

```java
@JsonCreator
public FilteredData(
        @JsonProperty("shipments")
        @JsonAlias("listShipments")
                List<ShipmentData> shipments) {
    this.shipments = shipments;
}
```

With this, you can deserialize with both `listShipments` and `shipments` while for serialization only `shipments` is used (defined by getter).

---

For reference, a working implementation with *2.3.3.RELEASE*:

```java
@RestController
public class FilteredDataController {

    @PostMapping("/data")
    public FilteredData postFilteredData(@RequestBody FilteredData data) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

```java
public class FilteredData {
    
    private final List<String> shipments;

    @JsonCreator
    public FilteredData(
            @JsonProperty("shipments") @JsonAlias("listShipments") 
                    List<String> shipments) {
        this.shipments = shipments;
    }

    public List<String> getShipments() {
        return shipments;
    }
}
```

*Request:*

```
curl -d '{"listShipments":["a","b","c"]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/data
```

*Result:*

```json
{"shipments":["a","b","c"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were breaking changes between Spring Boot 1 and Spring Boot 2. Have you tried anything to fix it already? E.g. attempted to move the JsonProperty annotation to field rather than constructor? or using @JsonCreator

online resource: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects

Comment: Tried both. Exact same behavior